# Tensorflow while_loop is throwing error when I attach the tag tf.function

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
@tf.function
def manu_data(dats):
    print("Manufacturing train data...")

    dats = tf.transpose(dats, [1, 0, 2, 3])
    dats, train_adata = dats[0], dats[1]
    train_idata = tf.zeros([0, 15, 15], tf.int32)

    def body(i, train_idata, dats):
        train_idata = tf.reshape( \
                    tf.concat( \
                        [ \
                            tf.slice(train_idata, [0, 0, 0], [i, 15, 15]), \
                            tf.reshape(tf.cast(tf.divide(tf.add(tf.square(dats[i]), dats[i]), 2), tf.int32), [-1, 15, 15]), \
                            tf.reshape(tf.cast(tf.divide(tf.subtract(tf.square(dats[i]), dats[i]), 2), tf.int32), [-1, 15, 15]), \
                            tf.reshape(tf.cast(tf.subtract(1, tf.square(dats[i])), tf.int32), [-1, 15, 15]), \
                            tf.zeros([dats.shape[0] - i - 1, 15, 15], tf.int32) \
                        ], 0), \
                    [-1, 15, 15])
        if tf.equal(tf.math.mod(tf.add(i, 1), 1000), 0): tf.print(i)
        return [tf.add(i, 1), train_idata, dats]
    i = tf.constant(1)
    tf.while_loop( \
        lambda i, train_idata, dats: tf.less(i, dats.shape[0]), \
        body, [i, train_idata, dats], parallel_iterations = 16)
    train_idata = tf.reshape(train_idata, [-1, 3, 15, 15])
    return (train_idata, train_adata)
```

My code runs well when I remove "@tf.function" at the top of the code. But otherwise, I got this messege:

```
ValueError: Input tensor 'zeros:0' enters the loop with shape (0, 15, 15), but has shape (None, 15, 15) after one iteration.
```

I think it means that the tensor 'train_idata' became a tensor in shape[None,15, 15] while using tf.while_loop. Can anyone notice what the problem is??

Edit: Thanks to Andrea, I edited my code like this:

```
tf.while_loop( \
    lambda i, train_idata, dats: tf.less(i, dats.shape[0]), \
    body, [i, train_idata, dats], parallel_iterations = 16, \
    shape_invariants = [i.shape, train_idata.shape, tf.TensorShape([None, 15, 15])])
```

And I got another error:

```
ValueError: Tried to convert 'y' to a tensor and failed. Error: None values not supported.
```

which means, I can't declare tf.TensorShape from array with None value.
What should I do?

Could you show me more detail? I'm a tensorflow newbie:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [mentioned by Andrea Angeli](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61820579/1782792), you need to give a `shape_invariants` parameter to your loop. In addition to that, there are several simplifications that could be made in your code. You don't need any of the `\` at the end of new lines (you can break lines in Python if you are within parentheses, brackets or braces). Most TensorFlow operations can be expressed in a simpler way using regular mathematical operators. And a couple other details. Here is how it could work:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

@tf.function
def manu_data(dats):
    # Use tf.print so it gets printed on every call,
    # not just the first one
    tf.print("Manufacturing train data...")

    dats = tf.transpose(dats, [1, 0, 2, 3])
    dats, train_adata = dats[0], dats[1]
    train_idata = tf.zeros([0, 15, 15], tf.int32)

    def body(i, train_idata, dats):
        train_idata = tf.reshape(
            tf.concat([
                train_idata[:i, :15, :15],
                tf.reshape(tf.cast((tf.square(dats[i]) + dats[i]) / 2, tf.int32), [-1, 15, 15]),
                tf.reshape(tf.cast(tf.square(dats[i]) - dats[i] / 2, tf.int32), [-1, 15, 15]),
                tf.reshape(tf.cast(1 - tf.square(dats[i]), tf.int32), [-1, 15, 15]),
                tf.zeros([tf.shape(dats)[0] - i - 1, 15, 15], tf.int32)], axis=0),
            [-1, 15, 15])
        # Change printing to be "graph-friendly"
        maybe_print = tf.cond(tf.equal(i + 1 % 1000, 0),
            lambda: tf.print(i),
            lambda: tf.group([]))  # No-op
        with tf.control_dependencies([maybe_print]):
            return [i + 1, train_idata, dats]
    i = tf.constant(1)
    _, train_idata, _ = tf.while_loop(
        # Better use tf.shape to support dynamic shape
        lambda i, train_idata, dats: i < tf.shape(dats)[0],
        body,
        [i, train_idata, dats],
        # Use shape invariants to support variable shapes
        shape_invariants=[tf.TensorShape(()), tf.TensorShape((None, 15, 15)), dats.shape],
        parallel_iterations=16)
    train_idata = tf.reshape(train_idata, [-1, 3, 15, 15])
    return (train_idata, train_adata)

# Test
out = manu_data(tf.zeros((100, 2, 15, 15), tf.float32))
```

In any case, you are not collecting the results of [`tf.while_loop`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/while_loop), so I think you may be misunderstanding its purpose. Look at the documentation of the function and the examples, you are supposed to take the outputs it produces as results - probably you want something like `_, train_idata, _ = tf.while_loop(...)`. Also, it is usually not recommendable to add rows to a tensor in a loop like that, in most cases there are better ways to do the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

When using a tf.while_loop with Autograph (tf.function) all loop variables have to maintain shape across iterations. In your code, train_idata starts with a shape (0,15,15) but during the  `tf.concat` call TF cannot infere the 0th dimension, so it uses None which means ("infere this at runtime").
If you want to change the shapes across iterations, you should use the `shape_invariant` parameter.

You can read more about the limitations of Autograph [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/autograph/g3doc/reference/limitations.md#consistency-of-shape).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the original code intended to calculate, but here it is simplified a little to take advantage of the defined operators so that there is less clutter due to function calls. I think you also want `i` to start with 0, not 1, given the initial value of `train_idata`:

```
@tf.function
def manu_data(dats):
    tf.print("Manufacturing train data...")

    dats = tf.transpose(dats, [1, 0, 2, 3])
    dats, train_adata = dats[0], dats[1]
    train_idata = tf.zeros([0, 15, 15], tf.int32)

    i = 0
    while i < dats.shape[0]:
      tf.autograph.experimental.set_loop_options(
          parallel_iterations=16
      )
      train_idata = tf.reshape(
          tf.concat(
              [
               train_idata[0:i, 0:15, 0:15],
               tf.reshape(tf.cast(tf.square(dats[i]) + dats[i] / 2, tf.int32), [-1, 15, 15]),
               tf.reshape(tf.cast(tf.square(dats[i]) - dats[i] / 2, tf.int32), [-1, 15, 15]),
               tf.reshape(tf.cast(1 - tf.square(dats[i]), tf.int32), [-1, 15, 15]),
               tf.zeros([dats.shape[0] - i - 1, 15, 15], tf.int32)
              ],
              0),
              [-1, 15, 15])

      if i + 1 % 1000 == 0:
        tf.print(i)

      i += 1

    train_idata = tf.reshape(train_idata, [-1, 15, 15])
    return train_idata, train_adata

manu_data(tf.ones([30, 2, 15, 15], dtype=tf.float32))
```

This ran without error in my tests, but I'm not sure that is has the inputs/outputs you expect.